# Как в python работать с Api Яндекса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск-библиотек

Не могу понять как в `Python` работать с геокодером Яндекса. Какую библиотеку использовать?

Сама задача: `Python` отправляет определенный координаты адреса (55.760241, 37.611347), нужно получить адрес (например, г. Москва, ул. Тверская, д. 6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests

API_KEY = "Ваш ключ"

def get_address(lat, lon):

    URL = f"https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey={API_KEY}&geocode={lat},{lon}&format=json&sco=latlong&kind=house&results=1&lang=ru_RU"
    result = requests.get(URL).json()
    return result['response']['GeoObjectCollection']['featureMember'][0]['GeoObject']['metaDataProperty']['GeocoderMetaData']['text']
```

Comment: что за данные lot, lon?

Comment: ваши географические координаты(55.760241, 37.611347)